# How to $set new Date() in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have tried quite a few combinations and checked the MongoDB 3.2 docs, but I still am not getting my new Date() stored in my DB. Everything else below is getting properly stored. Thanks in advance for any tips!

Code from my app.js file:

```
db.collection('users').update({user: req.user.username}, {
                    $push: {
                        "recentPlays": {
                            "quiz": req.session.mostRecentQuiz,
                            "score": score
                        }
                    }
                },{
                    $set: {
                        "mostRecentQuiz.quizObj": req.session.mostRecentQuiz,
                        "mostRecentQuiz.time"   : new Date() // StackOverflow: this is the part that is not getting stored in the DB.
                    }
                }, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(result);
                });
```

Comment: Try to store timestamp instead of object: "Date.now()" instead of "new Date()"

Comment: @Nosyara thanks for your reply. I just tried Date.now() and it does not work either. "new Date()" works elsewhere in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update method is being called the wrong way, the update operators `$set` and `$push` should be in the same document. Re-write your method as:

```
db.collection('users').update(
    { "user": req.user.username }, 
    {
        "$push": {
            "recentPlays": {
                "quiz": req.session.mostRecentQuiz,
                "score": score
            }
        }
        "$set": {
            "mostRecentQuiz.quizObj": req.session.mostRecentQuiz,
            "mostRecentQuiz.time"   : new Date() 
        }
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```